# AWS Amplify + Vuejs - federated sign in

Tags: vue.js, authentication, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-vue

I'm creating a basic app using AWS Amplify + Vue and I want to add federated authentication.
The authentication works okay, except the UI component is not showing the Federated Sign In buttons (as I expected). I configured Google Auth for now and it seems to work fine, but on my real Auth page there's no Google sign in button (only classic elements - username+password).

This is what I'm using to display the auth components:

```
<template>
  <div class="auth">
      <amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>
      <amplify-sign-out v-if="isAuthenticated"></amplify-sign-out>
  </div>
</template>
```

What should I do in order to display the Google button too? I can't find any tutorial/documentation related to Vue + Amplify federated sign in, only classic sign in.

Comment: don't you have to setup in the UI? I had to do something in the `Cognito > User Pools > App integration > UI customization`